# How about performance for the $near operation in mongodb(meteor)

Tags: performance, mongodb, search, meteor

I am using meteor to implement a 'near' query. 
In fact, it works well. But I am wondering how about the performance for server side.

This is the code for near query:

```
        var geolocation = Session.get('location');
        var lnglat = [0,0];
        if(geolocation){
          lnglat = [geolocation.longitude,geolocation.latitude];
        }
        if(Session.get('type') === 'near'){
            return Posts.find({
              location: {
                $near: {
                  $geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: lnglat
                  },
                  $maxDistance: 20000   //meters
                }
              }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "performance" and "server side"? Do you mean how will mongodb perform when I have a lot more items in my database? What are you expecting an answer to look like?

Comment: I don't want to use the search in wrong way actually. And I'm not familiar on mongodb so the question is not perfect. And I think Mario's answer is the best.

Comment: @codsimba As Mário suggested, reading the docs usually helps if one is unfamiliar with a technology. After doing so, some transfer of learning needs to take place. Creating test data turned out to be pretty efficient for performance tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer lies in the mongodb source code in github (obviously! duh!). According to the documentation, its important to ensure the indexes. Link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/